# Check if new entry has been added - MySql

Tags: php, mysql

This is my existing MySql table

```
------  ------
 c_id    d_id 
------  ------      
  C1      20
  D2      21
  D3      22
  C2      22
  D1      21
```

Then `2 new` entries will happen

```
  C3      22
  D1      33
```

Here based on `d_id` , new entry `33` which is unique has been added. How do i know new value has been added, ignoring the duplicates.

My Query

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT d_id FROM tablename GROUP BY d_id";
```

After getting unique `d_id's` how to find newly added `d_id`?

Comment: A neat way would be to create a trigger.

Comment: dont you have an `auto_increament primary key` in your table???

Comment: @Daan, I am new to the trigger concept. Thanks will look into it.

Comment: @NishantSolanki, there is no AI in my table.

Comment: @RAcharaya than you should use a primary key in your table.. than  just use a query `SELECT d_id FROM tablename order by primary_key desc limit 1`... it will give you the last added d_id

Comment: d_id=33 is unique or same as other also there in your table.

Comment: @user, At this instance 33 is unique. If i get one more entry as '33' again. Then it becomes duplicate.. So for this instance i need to get newly added 'd_id' which should be unique..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the new value before inserting to table.

Do like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE d_id = 33";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0){
// Insert
}else{
// Not Insert
}
```

Let me know for further help.

Comment: But i want to run my query after insertion. Thanks for your time.